# I can't seem to get v.push.back() to work with strings

Tags: c++, string, push-back

```
// ConsoleApplication25.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace System;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    string x;

    cout << "Enter words followed by end of file: " << endl;

    while (cin >> x){
        words.push_back(x);
    }
    cout << endl;

    int count=0;
    string Uword;

    cout << "Enter the word you want me to count" << endl;
    cin >> Uword;

    for(int i = 0; i < (int)words.size(); ++i){
        if (Uword == words[i]){
            ++count;
        }
```

}

```
    cout << "You word appeared " << count << " times" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Can some one tell me what I did wrong ? :/ Clearly I don't understand a key concept. The program keeps skipping my second `cin`. and doesn't even look at the for loop and I don't have any idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first while loop reads until end-of-file... after end of file your stream state has EOF bit set, which is why that loop exits.  It's also why the next attempt to `cin >> Uword` exits without doing anything.  If you'd written something like...

```
if (!(cin >> UWord))
{
     std::cerr << "unable to read uword from cin\n";
     return 1;
}
```

...(generally a good habit) you'd have noticed the failure.

A typical approach to this problem is to have a "sentinel" word that denotes the end of the set of words... for example:

```
std::cout << "Enter valid words followed by the sentinel <END>:\n";
while (std::cin >> x && x != "<END>")
    words.push_back(x);
```

You'd definitely want to use an `if` test when reading `Uword` afterwards, so you can recognise and handle having hit EOF without seeing `<END>`.

Alternatively, get them to enter `Uword` first then let the loop reading all words run until EOF....

It's noteworthy that for some copilers/environments, `cin` can "experience" multiple EOFs... for example, pressing Control-Z on an otherwise empty line at the Windows CMD.EXE prompt generates an EOF, but you can keep reading from `cin` afterwards if you call `cin.clear()` to reset the EOF bit.  That said, if you write programs to rely on this then there's no way to automatically invoke/use/test them using statements like:

```
echo word1 word2 word3 word2 <END> word2 | ./word_counter_app

cat test_case_1 | ./word_couner_app

./word_couner_app < ./test_cast_2
```

That kind of invocation's useful enough that it's best avoiding trying to read post-EOF even if you don't care about portability.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` will have EOF set after your first loop. So before you input anything else, you just need to clear it:

```
cin.clear();
cin >> UWord;
```